# AccountChangeEvent fired multiple times

Tags: change-data-capture

After the publish of this article:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/06/get-buildspiration-with-asynchronous-apex-triggers-in-summer-19.html

I'm trying to implement an async apex trigger on Account.

This is the trigger:

```
trigger AccountAsyncTrigger on AccountChangeEvent (after insert) {
    Set<String> newAccSetId = new Set<String>();
    List <Account> accToUpdate = new List <Account>();

    for (AccountChangeEvent acc_i : Trigger.New) {
        EventBus.ChangeEventHeader header = acc_i.ChangeEventHeader;
        System.debug('Received change event for ' + header.entityName +' for the ' + header.changeType + ' operation.'); 
        List<String> recordIds = acc_i.ChangeEventHeader.getRecordIds();
        newAccSetId.addAll(recordIds);
    }
    Map <Id,Account> accountsMap = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,Partner_Type__c from Account where Id IN : newAccSetId]);
    if(!accountsMap.isEmpty()){
        for(AccountChangeEvent acc_i : Trigger.New){
            Account acc = accountsMap.get(acc_i.ChangeEventHeader.getRecordIds()[0]);
            if(acc.Partner_Type__c != null){
                acc.isPartner = true;
            }
            else{     
                acc.isPartner = false;
            }
            accToUpdate.add(acc);
        }

        try {
            if(!accToUpdate.isEmpty()){
                update accToUpdate;
            }
        } catch (DmlException ex) {
            Trigger.New.get(0).addError(ex);
        }  
    }
}
```

i ran debug logs on "Automated Process", and tried to insert an account.
For some reason, the Automated Process keeps updating the account in an infinite loop:
[image]

I have no idea why this happens, and when i looked in the log, only "AfterInsert" (The Async Trigger),"BeforeUpdate" and "AfterUpdate" are running.

Anyone has an idea why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying a record, which triggers an AccountChangeEvent, which modifies a record, which triggers an AccountChangeEvent... and so on. This is expected behavior. It is unclear why you're using a change event here, since it would be more appropriate to do this in an Account.BeforeUpdate handler instead:

```
trigger AccountPartnerCheck on Account (before update) {
  for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
    record.IsPartner = record.Partner_Type__c != null;
  }
}
```

If you must use this AccountChangeEvent.AfterInsert (e.g. because of Process Builder, etc), you need to check to see if the value actually changed in order to break the infinite loop:

```
trigger AccountAsyncTrigger on AccountChangeEvent (after insert) {
    Set<String> newAccSetId = new Set<String>();
    for (AccountChangeEvent acc_i : Trigger.New) {
        newAccSetId.addAll(acc_i.ChangeEventHeader.getRecordIds());
    }
    Account[] accToUpdate = [
      SELECT Partner_Type__c from Account 
      where Id IN : newAccSetId and (
        (ispartner = false and partner_type__c != null) 
        or
        (ispartner = true and partner_type__c = null))];
    for(Account record: accToUpdate) {
        record.IsPartner = record.Partner_Type__c != null;
    }
    Database.update(accToUpdate, false);
}
```

Here, we additionally filter the query to show only records that need to be updated (i.e. the field shows IsPartner equals true but has no type, or isPartner equals false but has a type).

This will prevent the infinite loop, since we only update records that need to be modified.

Comment: I'm not using beforeUpdate because the field "isPartner" is not writeable + i want to move this to AccountChangeEvent to avoid hitting limits.
A few questions:
1. isn't the "after insert" enables the trigger to run only when inserting a record and the event is fired?
2. Why are u using Database.update instead of just update?
3. Where are you checking if there was a change?

Comment: @DanaGriff (1) No, After Insert for the Change Event refers to *any* change to a record, including updates. This is the cause for the infinite loop. (2) So that as many records as possible can be updated. Using the try-catch mechanism can result in far more data loss. (3) I check to see if the flag and the field agree with each other (this is why the OR filter is there). If they do not, then I know they need to be updated.

Comment: So why do you need the "after insert" annotation?

Comment: @DanaGriff because the change event is being created. It does not refer to the record being created, but rather the event.

Comment: Got it, Thanks!